# Getting specific value out of response object

Tags: angular, typescript

I been playing around with Angular 2 and trying to implement handing of errors.

Now I have scenario where I POST to an API, and I want it to output the message that gets returned from the API if it's a bad request (400).

This is the code so far, not sure how to get to next stage.

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8088/api/NextLevel', JSON.stringify(value), options)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .catch((error: any) => { this.handleError(error); });

private handleError(error: any) {
if( error.status == '400') {
// output to console the data contained for key Message
}
}
```

This is example of JSON object that gets returned:

```
{Message: "The level is not recorded", ModelState: Object}
```

Basically I want to output to console the message "The level is not recorded".

Comment: Please add to your question `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));`

Comment: Does this code work?

Comment: @RomanC yup does

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your response mime type is.

If it's JSON you want

```
response.json().data.Message OR

response.json().Message
```

If it's text you want

```
response.text()
```

Comment: what is the mime type of the response? you might need to tell your server to set the JSON response header before .json() works

Comment: already receiving json format, and as such able to display as json object in console